# How to Debug java variables and execute methods on the variables from terminal?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a code similar to this

```
Optional.ofNullable(insight)
        .map(i -> i.getValues())
        .map(values -> values.get(0))
        .map(v -> v.getValue())
        .orElse(0);
```

I am trying to debug it and use different methods on it from IntelliJ debugger, I am used to that using chrome debugger for JavaScript.
Let say if it wasn't a stream and just a normal list of something similar will I be able to execute list methods on it from the treminal. 
 Like if you have a variable name="myName" in the console you can do 
`name.WhateverStringMethod` to see the result of that.

My question is can I see the result of each of those lines and debug let's say i or values inside the second map.

If that is not possible can you please recommand a way to debug a code like that. 
I am really a newbie to Java and this is my second week.
Thanks,

Comment: My example is using a stream but it can be an argument passed to a function or something like that. Can we still execute methods from the terminal.